# How to efficiently load last item in ArrayCollection?

Tags: performance, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following 2 entities:

```
public class Domain {
    ...
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Ping", mappedBy="domain", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
    * @ORM\OrderBy({"time" = "ASC"})
    */
    private $pings;
    ...
}
```

and:

```
class Ping{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Domain", inversedBy="pings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="proj_id", referencedColumnName="proj_id")
    */
    private $domain;
    ...
 }
```

I have currently a couple of hundred domains with 5K-8K Pings each in my tables.

In an overview of the domains - limited to 50 domains per page - I want to display the count of all pings and the result of the last ping. While displaying the count of the collection works without any issues  I can't fetch the last element of the collection efficiently.

I tried to get the element with

```
$domain->getPings()->last();
```

and

```
$domain->getPings()->get( $key );
```

In both cases the result is the same:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted ...

How can i get the last ping efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter your collection efficiently in the entity without the need for the repository you can use a [`Criteria`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections). It will allow to filter a collection that's been already loaded into memory or do it directly in sql if not. Quoting from the documentation:

> If the collection has not been loaded from the database yet, the
>   filtering API can work on the SQL level to make optimized access to
>   large collections

Just add the following method to your `Domain` Entity.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

// ...

/**
 * Get last ping for the domain.
 * @returns Ping
 */
public function getLastPing()
{
    $c = Criteria::create();
    $c->setMaxResults(1);
    $c->orderBy(['time' => Criteria::DESC]);
    $this->pings->matching($c)->first();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error is gone, and after adding an index on the time column the page loads in less than a second.