# Query specific field with doctrine returns object array null

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm facing what I think is a really easy task (or it should be at least), I've seen a lot of related questions and try to resolve my own problem with them with no luck at all, this is why I'm writing my own question here.

I want to be able to gather the average temperature from my table within the last 7 rows, i.e the average temperature for the last 7 days.

If I query my database using this simple query I obtain a result that matches my requirements:

`select avg(m.temperatura) as temperature from (SELECT temperatura from database.meteodata order by indice desc limit 7) m`

But, the problem is trying to move that query into doctrine with PHP.

I'm new to doctrine. I'm building a API using slim framework (version 3). I have a database with a table following this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `meteodata` (
  'indice' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'timestamp' timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  'temperatura' float DEFAULT NULL,
  'humedad' float DEFAULT NULL,
  'viento' float NOT NULL,
  'direccion_viento' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'lluvia' float NOT NULL,
  'summary' varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  'icon' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('indice')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=562 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I also have an entity class to match that table into my PHP classes like following:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="meteodata")
 */
class MeteoStation implements JsonSerializable
{
    /** @ORM\Id()
     *  @ORM\Column(name="indice", type="integer")
     *  @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $indice;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false) */
    protected $timestamp;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="viento", type="float") */
    protected $wind;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="temperatura", type="float") */
    protected $temperature;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="humedad", type="float") */
    protected $humidity;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="lluvia", type="float") */
    protected $rain;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="direccion_viento", type="integer") */
    protected $dirViento;

    /** @ORM\Column(length=100)  */
    protected $summary;

    /** @ORM\Column(length=20) */
    protected $icon;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIndice()
    {
        return $this->indice;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $indice
     */
    public function setIndice($indice)
    {
        $this->indice = $indice;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTimestamp()
    {
        return $this->timestamp;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $timestamp
     */
    public function setTimestamp($timestamp)
    {
        $this->timestamp = $timestamp;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getWind()
    {
        return $this->wind;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $wind
     */
    public function setWind($wind)
    {
        $this->wind = $wind;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTemperature()
    {
        return $this->temperature;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $temperature
     */
    public function setTemperature($temperature)
    {
        $this->temperature = $temperature;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getHumidity()
    {
        return $this->humidity;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $humidity
     */
    public function setHumidity($humidity)
    {
        $this->humidity = $humidity;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getRain()
    {
        return $this->rain;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $rain
     */
    public function setRain($rain)
    {
        $this->rain = $rain;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDirViento()
    {
        return $this->dirViento;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $dirViento
     */
    public function setDirViento($dirViento)
    {
        $this->dirViento = $dirViento;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSummary()
    {
        return $this->summary;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $summary
     */
    public function setSummary($summary)
    {
        $this->summary = $summary;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIcon()
    {
        return $this->icon;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $icon
     */
    public function setIcon($icon)
    {
        $this->icon = $icon;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            "index" => $this->getIndice(),
            "timestamp" => $this->getTimestamp(),
            "wind" => $this->getWind(),
            "temperature" => $this->getTemperature(),
            "humidity" => $this->getHumidity(),
            "wind_direction" => $this->getDirViento(),
            "rain" => $this->getRain(),
            "summary" => $this->getSummary(),
            "icon" => $this->getIcon()
        ];

    }
}
```

The problem here is that the return result is always `null`.

I have a repository field with this method:

```
    public function getLastAvgTemp()
    {
        $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->entityManager);
        $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('MeteoStation', 'm');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('m', 'temperatura', 'temperature');
        $query = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery("select avg(m.temperatura) as temperatura from (SELECT temperatura from vinesens.meteodata order by indice desc limit 7) m", $rsm);
        $data = $query->getResult();
        var_dump($data);
        //return $data;
    }
```

The result is

```
nullarray(1) {
  [
    0
  ]=>
  NULL
}
```

I know it has to be something easy, because if I change the query to this one (just retrieving the last 7 data) (I know it would be done differently it's just for the sake of the question)

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->entityManager);
        $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('MeteoStation', 'm');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('m', 'temperatura', 'temperature');
        $query = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery("select * from (SELECT * from vinesens.meteodata order by indice desc limit 7) m", $rsm);
        $data = $query->getResult();
        var_dump($data);
```

Then it returns all my values with the appropriate data.

So I think it has something to do with selecting only one particular column from the table and I don't know how to fix it because if I change the query to this:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->entityManager);
        $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('MeteoStation', 'm');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('m', 'temperatura', 'temperature');
        $query = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery("select m.temperatura as temperatura from (SELECT temperatura from vinesens.meteodata order by indice desc limit 7) m", $rsm);
        $data = $query->getResult();
        var_dump($data);
```

It returns 7 null objects like so:

```
array(7) {
  [
    0
  ]=>
  NULL
  [
    1
  ]=>
  NULL
  [
    2
  ]=>
  NULL
  [
    3
  ]=>
  NULL
  [
    4
  ]=>
  NULL
  [
    5
  ]=>
  NULL
  [
    6
  ]=>
  NULL
}
```

Please, if you need more information don't hesitate to ask me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670661) help you, or would you rather do it in sql ?

Comment: try `->getArrayResult()`